# Revoking an existing SSL certificate and installing a new one instead of renewing

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

GoDaddy's SSL renewals are mighty expensive compared to purchasing new ones. I have a site that isn't that heavily used on weekends. I'm thinking of "revoking" my existing, valid SSL certificate and then installing the new one for the same domain.

Does this have any lasting impact or any negative fallout?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine. Anyone who's stolen your certificate will get revoked (if that's the case), and your users will happily continue to browse your website uninterrupted.

That said, there's no point in doing this unless your certificate is up for renewal. Otherwise, wait until the renewal is up and then do it.

Comment: No one stole the certificate - and yes, the cert is up for renewal. GoDaddy has a huge differential pricing on new and renewal certs and I can afford the 'gap' in SSL security coverage... Thanks for the inputs Far!

Comment: If the certificate is about to expire, then there is no need to revoke it. Just start using the new one.